# Strugling with UITableViews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I cannot program a UITableView to save my life, apparently. I have gone through several websites includin other Stack Overflow posts but they all give me errors such as:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0x7fe671006d00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableview.'
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction for working examples of UITableViews?

Comment: What are you trying to set for the tableview using KVO? o.O

Comment: @RakeshaShastri eventually I am going to queue strings from a server, but for now, I am trying to use hard-coded arrays of strings to populate the list

Comment: You are doing something really wrong. KVO is not required for that. You need to show your code where you do that.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, I don't have any code to show because everything I have coded related to the table view throws an error unless you want the broken code, but all it is is the solution to someone else's UITableView question. What I currently have coded: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309205/populate-table-view-in-swift

Comment: Well it seems to be an .xib issue. So... :x

Comment: @RakeshaShastri just thought I'd inform you I was able to get the UITableView working, I'm not sure why it was not working before though.